# controlling vertical scroll bar in silverlight autocompletebox

Tags: silverlight, autocompletebox

I have a Silverlight application that uses the AutoCompleteBox. This AutoCompleteBox is defined as follows:

```
  <sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="myAutoCompleteBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    MaxHeight="240" MaxDropDownHeight="240" IsTextCompletionEnabled="False"    
    MinimumPrefixLength="4" MinimumPopulateDelay="100"                 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyElements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" />
```

I want the vertical scroll bar in the drop down list to always be visible. This way I can size my item template appropriately. My question is, How do I always display the vertical scroll bar in the drop down box of an autocompletebox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `VerticalScrollbarVisibility` on the containing `ScrollViewer`.  You may be able to accomplish this by creating an Implicit `Style` within the `AutoCompleteBox` `Style`, as shown below.  Otherwise you'll need to create a Style for the `AutoCompleteBox` and set the Property or `Style` on the `ScrollViewer` directly.

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="myAutoCompleteBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    MaxHeight="240" MaxDropDownHeight="240" IsTextCompletionEnabled="False"    
    MinimumPrefixLength="4" MinimumPopulateDelay="100"                 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyElements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}">
    <sdk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Style>
     </sdk:AutoCompleteBox.Resources>
</sdk:AutoCompleteBox>
```